# Не работает плеер на странице

Tags: java, jquery

В одном из полей сущности хранится музыкальная композиция (также есть текст и картинка), сущность хранится в базе. Ajax запросом обращаюсь к Spring контролёру, достаю список сущностей из базы и json'ом отправляю на страницу, там прохожу по этому списку, отображаю текст, картинку, а вот с муз.композицией не выходит. В моей реализации каждому объекту отображаемого списка соответствует свой плеер, но это не обязательно, он может быть и один, например вверху страницы, а с помощью jQuery подставлять src соответствующего объекта (так пробовал, результат тот же). В отображаемом на странице списке на долю секунды появляется плеер и исчезает, подскажите, что не так?? Если указать src к файлу на диске, то всё ок, а вот к контролёру не работает((
Сущность

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long idMessage;

    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date date = new Date();

    private String text;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "LONGBLOB")
    @Lob
    private byte[] img;

    private String nameSong;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "LONGBLOB")
    @Lob
    private byte[] song;
```

Методы контролёра для загрузки сообщений, а так же поиска в базе изображения и муз.композиции

```
@RequestMapping("/upload/messages")
    public void uploadMessages(Model model,
                               HttpServletResponse response,
                               @ModelAttribute(value = "date") Date date) {

        List<Message> messageList = serviceMessage.findAllMessage(date);// загружаем полный стек сообщений
        if (!messageList.isEmpty()) {
            date = messageList.get(messageList.size() - 1).getDate();
            model.addAttribute("date", date);
        }

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = "";
        try {
            json = mapper.writeValueAsString(messageList);
            response.getWriter().println(json);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

        @RequestMapping("/find/img")
        public ResponseEntity<byte[]> findImg(HttpServletRequest request) {
            long idMessage = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("idMessage"));
            byte[] img = serviceMessage.findImg(idMessage);
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
            return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(img, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        @RequestMapping("/find/song")
        public ResponseEntity<byte[]> findSong(HttpServletRequest request) {
            long idMessage = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("idMessage"));
            byte[] song = serviceMessage.findSong(idMessage);
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.ALL);
            return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(song, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```

Разметка html, использую jsp страницу

```
...
    <div id="messageList">
        <%-- Message List... --%>
    </div>
...
```

Код jQuery

```
function UploadMessage() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "upload/messages",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false
        },
        success: SuccessUploadMessage
    })
}

function SuccessUploadMessage(result) {

    $.each(result, function (index, value) {
        var txt = value.text;
        var img = value.img;
        var nameSong = value.nameSong;

        if (txt != null || img != null || nameSong != null) {
            $("#messageList").prepend("<div id='oneMessage'></div>");// предварительно создаём отдельный блок для каждого сообщения

            if (txt != null) {// вставляем текст сообщения
                $("#oneMessage").append("<li id='myText' style='display: none'>" + value.text + "</li>");
                $("#myText").fadeIn(1500);
            }

            if (img != null) {// вставка изображения
                $("#oneMessage").append("<img id='myImg' src='' style='width: 140px; height: 100px; display: none'>");
                $("#myImg").attr("src", "find/img/?idMessage=" + value.idMessage);
                $("#myImg").show(800)
            }

            if (nameSong != null) {// вставляем аудиофайл
                $("#oneMessage").append("<audio id='mySong' controls='controls' src=''></audio>");
                $("#mySong").attr("src", "find/song/?idMessage" + value.idMessage)
            }

            $("#messageList").prepend("<br>")
        }
    });
}
```

Изменения внесённые в код относительно комментария от `br3t`.
Код jQuery теперь выглядит так:

```
function SuccessUploadMessage(result) {
    $.each(result, function (index, value) {
        var txt = value.text;
        var img = value.img;
        var nameSong = value.nameSong;
        var song = value.song;

        if (txt != null || img != null || nameSong != null) {
            $("#messageList").prepend("<div id='oneMessage'></div>");// предварительно создаём отдельный блок для каждого сообщения

            if (txt != null) {// вставляем текст сообщения
                $("#oneMessage").append("<li id='myText' style='display: none'>" + txt + "</li>");
                $("#myText").fadeIn(1500);
            }

            if (img != null) {// вставка изображения
                $("#oneMessage").append("<img id='myImg' src='' style='width: 140px; height: 100px; display: none'>");
                $("#myImg").attr("src", "data: image/png;base64," + img);// изменённая строка
                $("#myImg").show(800)
            }

            if (nameSong != null) {// вставляем аудиофайл
                $("#oneMessage").append("<audio id='mySong' controls='controls' src='striken.mp3' type='application/json'></audio>");
                $("#oneMessage").append("<p>" + nameSong + "</p>");
                $("#mySong").attr("src", "data: audio/mp3;base64," + song);// изменённая строка
                $("#mySong").show(800);
            }

            $("#messageList").prepend("<br>")
        }
    });
}
```

Скриншот плеера в браузере хром
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: т.е. бэкенд нормально возвращает адрес аудио-файла?

Comment: @br3t Бэкенд возвращает не адрес файла, а сам файл из базы в виде ResponseEntity<byte[]>

Comment: Почему бы не возвращать ссылкой? Почему не вернуть один объект с полями "изображение","текст","аудио"? + у вас явно какая-то ошибка в консоли должна быть.

Comment: @br3t Я так понимаю, чтобы вернуть ссылку, мне необходимо десериализировать из базы в файл муз.композицию?

Comment: В принципе вы можете использовать `data` в `src`  в base64 (http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/09/html5/html5-media-and-data-uri/ ) , но большие файлы лучше хранить не в базе, а на сервере.

Comment: @br3t Попробую по вашему совету, подскажите , зачем и почему кодировка base64 (я слабо знаком с фронтендом). Большие файлы хранятся в базе, т.к. они не статические.

Comment: Потому что base64 нормально воспринимается браузером. Но это обычно делают для маленьких изображений, экономя на количестве запросов к серверу.

Comment: @br3t Благодарю за ответ, всё работает.

Comment: @br3t Появился ещё вопрос. Сделав всё так, как вы посоветовали, я не опробовал результат во всех браузерах, а сделав это заметил, что подобный финт не работает в Opera version 47.0.2631.71 и в Chrome version 60.0.3112.113 (это те, которые установлены на моём пк). Подскажите, как это можно поправить или куда копать?

Comment: Добавьте пример неработающего кода.

Comment: @br3t Добавил пример кода, изменённые строки помечены соответственными комментариями. Данный код отлично себя ведёт в браузерах: мозила и встроенный в вин10 edge.

Comment: Должно работать http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri . Давайте и пример неработающего изображения.

Comment: @br3t Извините за тупизм, я не уточнил, данный код не работает только с аудио - плеер отображается, но пустой, скриншот я добавил в вопрос, см.выше. Изображения открываются таким образом во всех установленных браузерах.

Comment: Так аудио у вас в  wav или в mp3 ?

Comment: @br3t Пробовал и тот и тот формат, файлы не более 1.5Mb

Comment: @br3t Так же попробовал формат .ogg, результат тот же-плеер отображается пустым, без кнопки громкости и кнопки скачать

Comment: @br3t Т.е. плеер выглядит так, как если бы в src ничего не указывать